# Rainbowduino 3.0 - Arduino IDE fails to upload

Tags: software, arduino, programming-languages

OK, not really robotics, but has anyone been able to upload to a Rainboduino v3.0 using the Arduino IDE? I can't seem to figure it out, and there is virutally no documentation online. I followed [this blog entry](http://www.anyware.co.uk/2005/2012/01/17/getting-started-with-arduino-rainbowduino/), but got no connection to the board.

If anyone can give me some suggestions, I would appreciate it!

Comment: This is plenty related to robotics. How do you know you have no connectivity? How do you have it connected? Do you have any other arduino boards by chance that do work?

Comment: yeah, I've got an arduino uno R3 that works fine. I can connect and upload to that. I'm not sure what board to select with the rainbowduino, and there is little documentation. I was getting an error like "could not connect" or something like that, don't have it with me at the moment but will post the full error message later. Have you gotten one to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the Rainbowduino 3.0 uses an ATmega328, so first be sure to choose a board that's using that.

If that doesn't solve the problem, try looking at this [wiki article about the Rainboduino v3.0](http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/Rainbowduino_v3.0).

Comment: I think that did it, I was selecting a Atmega128 board!